# Viewing .ser file obtained by extracting a .jar file

Tags: java, serialization, jar, executable, executable-jar

I have a .jar file whose name is stanford-parser-2.0.4-models.
After extracting it, what i got is englishPCFG.ser file.

Can someone please suggest how to view the content of this file because with my programmers notepad and gedit all that I can view in this file is some foreign symbols and binary code.
For now I have no idea about ser files.

Thanks in advance for any help in this regard.

Comment: Try to deserialize that file first

Comment: @sachinpasalkar thanks for the help. :D
Can you suggest how to do it and sorry for acting totally as a beginner

Comment: @Mchttp: Find code snippet below as my answer ;)

Comment: @sachinpasalkar Is there something missing in the answer like main class etc.
This is a java file i guess, so can you suggest how to compile and run it using linux.
My ser filename is englishPCFG.ser

Answer (score 2):

As you want to deserialize the file. Find code snippet present below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class ReadFile{
    int i=0;

    public static void main(String args[]){  

        File f = new File(args[0]);

    try{

    ObjectInputStream obj = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
     System.out.println("The text : "+  obj.readObject());
     obj.close();
     System.out.println("Deserializing Operation Completly Successfully.");

    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

     }

    catch(FileNotFoundException fe){

     System.out.println("File not found ");

    } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }}    

}
```

Put the above code in file name with ReadFile.java
For compiling your code google it. I cant feed you everything :(

Comment: Where i have to add the filename?

Comment: You can pass it while running the code :). It should be whole path.
e.g. java ReadFile /my/file/path

Comment: An error is coming in the answer
----------
1. ERROR in demo.java (at line 7)
public class ConverToFile{
^^^^^^^^^^^^
The public type ConverToFile must be defined in its own file
----------
1 problem (1 error)

Comment: File name should be same as Class name. :) Please copy updated code and class name is changed ;)

Comment: Finally it has compiled without any error :) but yet another issue.
Its not outputting any of the following print command like deserialization successful or file not found etc.
Instead its showing just a line "edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser"
And ya when it will compile then where the utput will come like how will we finally  view the content of that file

Comment: How did you compile file ? And ran it?

Comment: first i used the command "javac demo.java"  without quotes
Then a demo.class is created.Then I used the command "java demo /my/ser/file/path"
these both commands were used in he same directory where files were present

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26295/discussion-between-sachin-pasalkar-and-mcolorz)